# Collection safer than standard list with generic type?

Tags: java, generics, java-6

I use generics in Java but it isn't so good as I thought

```
public static void add(List l, Object o) {
    l.add(o);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    add(list, "1.23");
    add(list, 1.23);
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

All this compiles and works. When I get a value from `list` an exception is thrown.

Can it be safer in Java 6?

Comment: Why don't you use the `list.add()` method ? Declare your `add()` method with generic `List<E>` parameter.

Comment: I understand, but I face type erasure (old code)

Comment: @KalamarObliwy : But it will save you from compile time errors and hence will save from `ClassCastExceptions` at run time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suggest using the standard `Collections`:

```
List<Integer> checked = Collections.checkedList(list, Integer.class);
```

then just work on `checked`. A `ClassCastException` will be thrown during the insertion of any non-compliant instance - sooner (thus better) than before (i.e. during retrieval).

N.B. check your compiler messages, I'd bet you have some warnings printed in there mentioning unsafe/unchecked code.. Your problem is exactly what the compiler is trying to tell you. If you control the signature of `add`, make it generic - it will give you compile-time safety.

```
public static <T> void add(List<T> list, T t) {
    list.add(t);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the `Collections.checkedList()` suggestion. However, `add()` should allow subtypes of the declared type to be inserted, so that if the list was declared as `List<Object>` the compiler would allow anything to be added. Therefore, `List<? super T>` would be a better fit than `List<T>`.

Comment: If the OP plans to **only add** to the `list`, then you're quite right. I was thinking more general.

Comment: An `add()` method should generally *only add* to a list ;) but on second thoughts, I think *I was wrong* :) : since it's about a collection and an element, the element will get "promoted" by the compiler to the super type transparently. What I said actually only applies to two generic types: `A<T>` and `B<T>` as these are invariant.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. If that static `add()` method is a fact of life (something you don't control), there's not much you can do, because Java generics are implemented so that they are compatible with Java < 5.0.

However, if you are able to change the signature of the `add()` method, you can simply enforce the type check so you get compiler errors for the code in your `main()` method:

```
public static <T> void add(List<? super T> list, T object) {
    list.add(object)
}
```